# Angular factory variable changes not reflected in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I've been trying to use a factory in my Angular app to be able to share and update variables between controllers, however I haven't had much luck. The app I'm working on basically receives messages into an inbox and then I can decide whether to show them on a visualizer for people to see. It's a real-time interactive app that would be used during a conference or something when the speaker wants to interact with the audience and see their responses to a question/statement.

I'm using a factory to keep track of the messages in the queue that will be displayed on the visualizer page. When I add a message into the queue from the inbox, it appears that the factory is being updated. However, on the visualizer page, the scope variables that are referencing the factory aren't being updated.

Here is my factory code:

```
angular.module('tellApp')
  .factory('VisualizerFactory', function () {

  return {
    queue: [],
    active: {},
    addToQueue: function(msg){
      this.queue.push(msg);
    }
  }

  });
```

Basically, from my inbox, I call the addToQueue function and pass in an object containing the message and some details. On the visualizer page all I'm doing is just looking at the VisualizerFactory object to see if it's updating and it's not. It just returns the empty VisualizerFactory object.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that you have a copy of the factory in your scope, which won't be updated since it's a different reference.

You can perhaps trigger a message from the service to notify the controller instance.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could you give me an example? I'm not sure how I would go about notifying the controller instance.

Comment: I've also tried using $watch to watch for changes in the factory and apply them to my local scope, but that hasn't worked either.